# Is returning a type pointer the same as 'newing a type'? in c#

Tags: c#, new-operator

Instead of...

```
Video v = new Video();
```

I want to do

```
Video v = GetVideo();

public Video GetVideo()
{
   return new Video();
}
```

Are these two calls totally equal?

Comment: Not really seeing what you're trying to accomplish. What you outline above has the same effect.

Comment: Your question title is very confusing :)

Comment: (1) there are no pointers involved here. (2) The expression “newing [up] a type” is so horrible that saying it out loud will release Yog-Sothoth from its prison beyond time. I don’t want to entice violence but whoever came up with this expression clearly is a satanist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're the same *in this case* because the method *also* creates a new `Video`. However, consider this instead:

```
private Video video;

public Video GetVideo()
{
   if (video == null)
   {
       video = new Video();
   }
   return video;
}
```

Now a new `Video` object will be created only the *first* call - subsequent calls will return a reference to the existing object.

(That's only a simple example, of course - it could *sometimes* create a new one, sometimes not, sometimes return null etc.)

Comment: And that's called a singleton :)

Comment: @Adrian - not really, it's an example of lazy loading

Comment: @CAbbott Yes, it is lazy loading. But also a singleton. If I call this method 10 times, how many times will the object  be a new one (excluding the first time)? How many times will the object be a different object? It's always the same instance being returned. Design patterns are not mutually exclusive. Most singleton implementations use lazy loading.

Comment: @Adrian: No, it's not a singleton. A singleton is a type which you can only ever get a single instance of. Here, `video` is an instance variable - so if you create a second instance of the container type, you can end up with a second instance of `Video`. There's no evidence that any type here is a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are. I have used this approach several times to return me an object prepopulated by some default testing values.

Answer (score 1):

> Is returning a type pointer the same as 'newing a type'?

It depends on the method returning the object reference.

Your given snippets, for example, are functionally equivalent because `GetVideo()` does nothing except return a `new Video()`.

Comment: Also depends if it is a value type.

Answer (score 1):

At least you can treat them as equal, they will probably be inlined to the same IL code if they reside in the same assembly.